# Uploaded images store in single image folder in Laravel Spatie Medialibrary

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-medialibrary

Laravel Spatie Medialibrary in
storing image in every time create new folder.
i want storage/image folder in all image.

mycode
[image]

now

[image]

i want this type

[image: i want this type]

Comment: Without any code examples we can't help you. We can't guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Please provide some useful context so that we can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.